# How to parse HTML file using PHP DOM module?

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I have following html file

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="list">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="http://website1.com" ><img src="image1.jpg"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://website2.com" ><img src="image2.jpg"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://website3.com" ><img src="image3.jpg"></a>
            </li>
            ....
            ....
            ....
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

By parsing the above html file. I want output like this..

```
 http://website1.com
 image1.jpg
 http://website2.com
 image2.jpg
 http://website3.com
 image3.jpg
 ....
 ....
```

By seeing above output, you can guess that I only need 'href' and 'src' value of each list item.

I am trying to parse by using 'simple_html_dom' 3rd party plugin.

```
<?php
  include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
  $html = new simple_html_dom();
  $html->load_file("html_file.html");
  foreach($html->find('div[class=list] ul li') as $li)
   {
     echo $li->find('a')->href."<br />";
     echo $li->find('img')->src."<br />";
   }
 ?>
```

but the above code doesn't work. Please tell me if i did anything wrong or else use can assist me by using PHP DOM module if you know.

Comment: This is not PHPs "DOM module", but an 3rd party library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<?php
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file("html_file.html");
    foreach($html->find('div.list a') as $a)
    {
        echo $a->href."<br />";
        echo $a->children(0)->src."<br />";
    }
?>`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding `div[class=list] ul li`'s, why don't you search for `.list li`'s? [Documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find) for Simple HTML DOM is quite lacking, so you'll need to pay around with it yourself, but this should work:

```
foreach($html->find('.list ul li') as $li)
```

If that still doesn't work, I'd `print_r($html->find('.list ul il')`, to see what that produces, and if that's an empty array, just cut back on the selectors until you can find the source of the problem (ie `print_r($html->find('.li ul')`, etc)

Comment: Oh, if my answer helped solved the problem, could you accept it? :)

Comment: both print_r($html->find('.list ul il')) and print_r($html->find('div[class=list] ul li') gives same output. it gives list of array elements..